# Javascript: convert array of objects to new array with objects that have a property value that is the same consecutively put into subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am converting InDesign files into ANF (Apple News Format, which is JSON) using Javascript.

In ANF you can only have one paragraph style per component (the equivalent of a text frame).

In InDesign there can be more that one paragraph style in a text frame. As a workaround, multiple components can be placed inside a container component to keep your layout correct.  To this end when I find a text frame in the InDesign document with multiple paragraph styles,  I create a container component and then create a component for each paragraph and nest it inside the container.

In the case where two or more **CONSECUTIVE** paragraphs in the text frame have the same paragraph style, I need to group them into one nested component.  I know this should be relatively simple, but the Javascript that works inside InDesign is a bit archaic, so a lot of the modern conveniences are not available.  I am needing to get creative with it.

Here's a simplified example of the data:

```
var textContainer = {
  role: "container",
  components: [
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>0</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>1</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>2</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>3</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>4</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>5</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>6</p>",
    }
  ]
}
```

So in the array there are two places where there are two groups of components same textStyle consecutively. I need to put these into one component. So the data should look like this when I'm done...

```
var textContainer = {
  role: "container",
  components: [
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>0</p><p>1</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>5</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>6</p>",
    }
  ]
}
```

essentially it should be `[[0,1],[2,3,4],5,6]`;

I've started like this:

```
var simplifiedComponents = [];
var consecutive = ""
for(i=0;i<textContainer.components.length;i++){
    if(i > 0 && i < textContainer.components.length - 1){
        if(textContainer.components[i].textStyle == textContainer.components[i+1].textStyle){
            textContainer.components[i].text += textContainer.components[i+1].text;
            textContainer.components[i+1].text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

But I got stuck.

Anyone have an idea of how I can convert my data to this optimized version?

**Again, I need to use basic Javascript here as most of the ES5 stuff isn't available to me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var textContainer = {
  role: "container",
  components: [
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>0</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>1</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>2</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>3</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>4</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-1",
      text: "<p>5</p>",
    },
    {
      textStyle: "style-2",
      text: "<p>6</p>",
    }
  ]
};

var simplifiedComponents = [];
var consecutive = ""
var components = textContainer.components;
for(var i = 0, l = components.length; i < l; i++){
  if (i !== 0 && components[i].textStyle !== components[i - 1].textStyle) {
    simplifiedComponents.push({text: consecutive, textStyle:components[i - 1].textStyle});
    consecutive = ""
  }
  consecutive = consecutive += components[i].text;
}
simplifiedComponents.push({text: consecutive, textStyle:components[components.length - 1].textStyle});


console.log(simplifiedComponents);
```

Comment: Thank you!  So simple.  I'm so used to using newer stuff that I couldn't remember how to do this the old way.

Comment: Pleasure. Yeah I love the simplicity that the 'new' stuff provides.